# Class not found : PackageParser when using PackageInstaller from git

Tags: android, installation, package, uninstallation

This is a very precise question about the package installer open source project hosted on google code project: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98

When I try to compile it, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` exception for this class:
`android.content.pm.PackageParser`.

I don't really understand what happens as this class is part of android sdk but not documented in android docs.

Did someone use that package before and knows how to compile it?

Comment: what api level are you using? have you tried an older version? can you post some of the code? i see what u mean about it not being documented :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You are trying to compile the PackageInstaller application, which is the application that Google ships as a part of the Android system, and which uses some API that are hidden from public SDK (like `android.content.pm.PackageParser`). There are few techniques available for accessing that hidden API, but even if you were able to compile PackageInstaller it won't run because it requires few permissions (like `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES`) that can be granted to the application only when it's signed with the System certificate. And only vendor of the device can do that.

But let me ask you, why do you need to compile PackageInstaller app? The author of the article at http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98 shows how to install/uninstall the *.apk* by sending the `Intent` to Google PackageInstaller application. You don't need to recompile PackageInstaller to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to pull out all the android code from the repository and compile it.
You can try download only the class you need and all it's dependencies.